# How to have some injections and some provided classes into a provided class

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm getting started with Dagger 2 and trying to work out how to get `@Inject` and `@Provides` to work together well. It's easy to get everything working when the top-level class is injected. Like this:

```
class TopLevelClass {

    @Inject
    SecondaryClass1 class1;

    private final SecondaryClass2 class2;

    @Inject
    TopLevelClass(SecondaryClass2 class2) {
        this.class2 = class2;
    }
}

@Module
class MyModule {

    @Provides
    SecondaryClass2 provideSecondaryClass2() {
        return new SecondaryClass2();
    }
}
```

However, everything stops working when I have to make a `@Provides` method for the top level class as well. Like this:

```
class TopLevelClass {

    @Inject
    SecondaryClass1 class1;

    private final SecondaryClass2 class2;

    TopLevelClass(SecondaryClass2 class2) {
        this.class2 = class2;
    }
}

@Module
class MyModule {

    @Provides
    TopLevelClass provideTopLevelClass(SecondaryClass2 class2) {
        return new TopLevelClass(class2);
    }

    @Provides
    SecondaryClass2 provideSecondaryClass2() {
        return new SecondaryClass2();
    }
}
```

With this example, I find that SecondaryClass1 never gets injected, so I get an NPE when I try to access it. Is there a different way that I'm supposed to do this for a provided top-level class?

P.S. I don't think it's relevant, but here's the component I'm using just in case it matters:

```
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class})
interface MyComponent {

    TopLevelClass getTopLevelClass();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, if you can, you should prefer `constructor` injection instead of `field` injection. In you case, it's possible. If you use `field` injection, you need somewhere call `Component.inject(target)` where target is class which fields marked with `@Inject` annotation - in that case dagger will construct all required instances and set them to appropriate fields.

Comment: Right, I would definitely prefer constructor injection over field injection as much as possible. I have to use `@Provides` sometimes due to things like configurable objects as well as when I need to return a specific implementation of an interface. Do I have to use field injection for those cases?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Make use of **constructor injection** and let Dagger create & inject the object (without any `@Provides` annotated method) The object will be ready to use without any need for code. This is where Dagger shines.
- Create the object *yourself* and make sure it is correctly set up before returning it from the `@Provides` annotated method

I don't know why you would prefer the second option, or why you would even want to use field injection when you can make use of the constructor, but, as you found out, fields won't be injected if you manually construct the object. None of the generated Dagger code will run—you'll have to do this yourself.

One way that comes to mind is to request the component and then inject the object.

```
@Provides
TopLevelClass provideTopLevelClass(SecondaryClass2 class2, MyComponent component) {
    TopLevelClass tlc = new TopLevelClass(class2);
    component.inject(tlc);
    return  tlc;
}
```

Comment: I find that I need to use `@Provides` often (for specific implementations of an interface, as well as any object that needs configuration). It seems to me that those are pretty common use cases. Am I unable to use injection with these types of objects?